# unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/ssh' before installing new version operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

Recently I met one troublesome problem with my lab ubuntu server. I want to reinstall my openssh server, so I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

However, the command failed with the feedback

```
Unpacking replacement openssh-server ... 
 dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/sbin/sshd' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
```

According to [one feasible solution](https://www.howtoforge.com/debian-ubuntu-unable-to-make-backup-link-of-usr-bin-sshd-before-installing-new-version-operation-not-permitted), I should check the attributes of my `/usr/bin/ssh` and `/usr/sbin/sshd` with `chattr` and `lsattr` command. But when I ran

```
sudo lsattr /usr/bin/ssh
sudo chattr /usr/bin/ssh
```

I saw no output. And it seems that my `lsattr`/`chattr` command is wrong cause I check the size of `lsattr` and `chattr`, they are 10576 b and 10592 b in my other ubuntu server. But in this server, they are only 10 b. And if I use `less -SN lsattr/chattr`, they all show:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/chattr (END)
```

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/lsattr (END)
```

And if I want to replace (with root) those `chattr` and `lsattr` with the one I copied from another server, it shows `Operation not permitted`.

So anyone could help me with this openssh problem or to reinstall `chattr`/`lsattr`?

Answer (score 2):

I recently experienced the same problem as you. All your previous actions are correct. But Before replacing `lsattr` and `chattr`, you need to modify the attributes of `/usr/bin/lsattr` and `/usr/bin/chattr` using the copied `chattr`.

```
sudo ./chattr -a -i /usr/bin/chattr
sudo ./chattr -a -i /usr/bin/lsattr
```

Then the replacement operation can be performed and you can modify the attributes of `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

```
sudo mv ./lsattr /usr/bin/lsattr 
sudo mv ./chattr /usr/bin/chattr 
sudo chattr -a -i /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Then you can try to install `openssh`.
To be on the safe side, finally add the `ai` attribute to both the replaced `lsattr` and `chattr`.

```
sudo chattr +a +i /usr/bin/chattr
sudo chattr +a +i /usr/bin/lsattr
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. Actually I reinstall chattr/lasttr in other path, then use the newly installed chattr/lasttr to remove the old chattr/lasttr, and then copy the newly installed chattr/lasttr to the /usr/bin, and use them to check/remove ssh, then I can install ssh.

Comment: Hope these could help people having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem, too.

Normally, the `/usr/bin/lsattr` file should be a binary executable, but I found it to be empty (with only one line `#!/bin/sh`).

This case, maybe we should not fix the problem by copying the correct `/usr/bin/lsattr` binary from another computer, but **we should be aware that our computers are attacked**!

The file `/usr/bin/lsattr` is replaced, and the `./usr/sbin/sshd` executable is modified, which means that **the ssh is not secure any more**! Attackers can log in to your computer, and take over the control. **Any private information is not secure any more......**

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing this out. I think OP should add some security checks, but I think assuming `/usr/sbin/sshd` was modified is a bit much. It's worthwhile to check the `sha256sum` of suspicious files against known copies of the same version, though.